# Cannot install rails with bundle due to uncanny compatibility problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle

I am willing to install Ruby on rails as follows. As gem install rails did not work, I created a demo folder and a Gemfile therein. I wrote these lines into it:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'arel', git: 'https://github.com/rails/arel.git'
```

I get the following error:

> rails was resolved to 7.0.0.alpha, which depends on
> actioncable was resolved to 7.0.0.alpha, which depends on
> actionpack was resolved to 7.0.0.alpha, which depends on
> actionview was resolved to 7.0.0.alpha, which depends on
> rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
> nokogiri was resolved to 1.12.4, which depends on
> racc

Haplessly, I do not know what is going wrong. Does anybody have a clue?

I have bundler 2.2.27 and ruby 3.0.2.

Comment: If you see error log carefully you do have a version conflict here. Try to update or set proper versions.

Comment: You shouldn't specify the `git:` unless you're specifically wanting to run on `edge` rails. I'd remove those and try again.